# How Mind Uploading could be done without being invasive?

Tags: brain, trans-humanism, mind

The timeline in the 22nd century section of FutureTimeline.net says that the brain will be replaced by robotic components until the brain is entirely artifitial and then be transplanted into a robotic body.

But I think it won't be necessary to cut a person's skull in order to remove the brain from inside it.It wouldn't even be needed to be transplanted.We could use a quantum computer to scan and simulate the person' brain up to atomic level and then according to its simulation create an artifitial replica inside the artifitial body using a nanofactory, which would create the synthetic brain as the organ is simulated at atomic level. During the process the person would be put into sleep or biostasis and when the patient wake up, their brain are artifitial and inside the robot. They would become an android and be no longer human.The person would wakeup as a brand new robot.In other words, the brain wouldn't even be needed to be transplanted.The organic body would be considered dead.Or the brain could be replaced inside the organic human body and then be teleported into the head of the robot body.

https://www.futuretimeline.net/22ndcentury/2100-2149.htm

Comment: You answered your own question there. I would advice you to either ask a question about your "answer" or post your answer as an actual answer to this thread so it can be discussed and up/downvoted independently of your question.

Comment: The only question is in your title, but you are asking how something that we don't know how to do could be done.  To answer this within a WB context you need to supply some details about what tech is available ( i.e. what tech will be available in your scenario that might make it possible ).

Comment: Please don't put a question and answer in one post. Leave the answer out or post it as an answer.

Comment: Are you asking us if what you're proposing is realistic?  If so, please edit your question to explain this and add the [tag:reality-check] tag.

Comment: @user18428 Please edit your question, as it has been tagged for closure. Cut your answer from the question, then paste your answer below as an actual answer.

Comment: Of course, if you have ready access to quantum computers and the technological ability to scan a brain "to the atomic level" through the skin, skull, membranes, pulsing blood vessels, and everything else in constant flux, you can do *way* more than merely copy the identity into a shiny new robot host. That's a bit like sending an expedition to the Antarctic to drill ice cores...that you merely use to chill drinks at your next party.

Comment: I downvoted this, because there's no question?!

Comment: Hmm ... Now would I prefer to have my brain simulation "as-is", complete with injuries and autism, or "repaired"?  Would the Android consciousness even be recognizably "me" if repairs were made in the transfer process?

Answer (score 1):

I would refer you to read `Old Man's War by John Scalzi`.

This book has the exact same scenario that you mentioned, with a difference that instead of transferring the consciousness into a mechanical android, they transfer it into an organic body, developed in some chambers.

They plant thousands of scanners into the brain, then let you do daily routine work and common problem solving for some time, then map the brain info pattern and simply copy paste it into another brain. Pretty easy !!